# Connect to mysql from eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

Please in short, how can i connect to MySQL from eclipse. If you can provide me a simple steps with an example please.

Comment: As it stands the question is unanswerable. You need to elaborate. Do you want a MySQL client, in that case get the Toad plugin.

Comment: You want to connect from eclipse IDE (i.e. plugin) or from a `Java` program written using eclipse?

Comment: Google JDBC - there's loads of step-by-step guides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("com.mysql.jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/NewStudents", "root", "root");

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = st.executeQuery("select * from students");

        while (result.next()) {
            .....
        }
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Driver not found");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

First parameter of getConnection is url, second username, third password.
Also import de jdbc driver by adding it to your library of your project.

There are better ways, but this one is simple for beginners.

Here is a link which does the same and it explains it more.

http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2003090401&page=1